# How to display buttons on navigation bar in UIPageViewController?

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uipageviewcontroller

I'm using a `UIPageViewController` connected to a `UINavigationController` to display two pages, a users table and a chat table.

I'm trying to implement the following:

Two buttons **`Users`** and **`Chat`** upon tapping which, the corresponding view controller appears. I want these buttons on the navigation bar.

Here's the code I've written in the page view controller class

```
viewDidLoad()

    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let vc1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("users")
    let vc2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("chat")

    vcArray = [vc1, vc2]

    self.setViewControllers([vc1], direction: .Forward, animated: true, completion: nil)

    let button1 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 30, self.view.frame.width/2, 30))
    let button2 = UIButton(frame: CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width/2+1, 30, self.view.frame.width/2, 30))
    button1.setTitle("Users", forState: .Normal)
    button2.setTitle("Chat", forState: .Normal)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView?.addSubview(button1)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.titleView?.addSubview(button2)
```

Unfortunately, none of the buttons appears in the navigation bar. 
In fact, I can't even assign a title to the navigation bar. How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can add multiple button on the right side of navigation bar like this

```
let editImage   = UIImage(named: "First")!
let searchImage = UIImage(named: "Second")!

let editButton   = UIBarButtonItem(image: editImage,  style: .Plain, target: self, action: "didTapEditButton:")
let searchButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: searchImage,  style: .Plain, target: self, action: "didTapSearchButton:")

navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [editButton, searchButton]
```

or

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar?.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [editButton, searchButton]
```

> If you want to make it look in the centre on the navigation bar, you
>   can use image with appropriate width so that it scales towards the center.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately, this does not solve the problem. I moved to RKSwipeViewController for built in functionality